# Is there any way to convert zipfile output to pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("files.zip",mode="r") as archive: 
   archive.printdir()
```

I want to convert the output of this code to a pandas dataframe.Is there any way for this as printdir() is returning a none type object.

Comment: You can use [archive.infolist()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.infolist)

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

If you [peek at what `printdir()` does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5c19050546e3e37a8889a0baa2954e1444e803d3/Lib/zipfile/__init__.py#L1457)
you can extrapolate this into something like

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("files.zip", mode="r") as archive:
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        [(zinfo.filename, zinfo.date_time, zinfo.file_size) for zinfo in archive.filelist],
        columns=["filename", "date_time", "file_size"],
    )
```

Comment: Thanks @AKX..It's working!

Comment: @Akx..why date time is not shown in proper format?

Comment: "proper format"?

Comment: yes..date_time is showing as tuple

Comment: Right, that's what `zinfo.date_time` is, a `(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)` tuple. You can do `datetime.datetime(*zinfo.date_time)` instead.

Comment: I tried the same..but it is not getting converted.

Comment: It definitely will get converted. What did you try?

Comment: def convert_df():
    with zipfile.ZipFile("files.zip", mode="r") as archive:
        df = pd.DataFrame(
            [(zinfo.filename, datetime.date(zinfo.date_time), zinfo.file_size) for zinfo in archive.filelist],
            columns=["filename", "date_time", "file_size"]
    )
        print(df.dtypes)

Comment: `datetime.date(zinfo.date_time)` is not what I commented above, which is `datetime.datetime(*zinfo.date_time)`.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'.This is giving me atrribute error

Comment: `import datetime`. Don't `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: Yes it worked..I thank you for your patient help :)